# hall effect potentiometer,linear output voltage .6 - 3.3v. How to reduce output to 1/2 the speed

Tags: voltage, voltage-regulator

What I have is a accelerator pedal that is putting out a voltage that the for whatever reason the Subaru ECU is interpreting at 2x the speed and this is normal. So 1/2 pedal movement is WOT at the throttle body.
The pedal is internally hall effect potentiometer and supplied with 5v.
So I only have control between .6v - 1.95v, from 1.95v - 3.3v the ECu ignores.

Being hall effect means I cannot simply reduce the 5v supply. I have to reduce the output but without having any arduino knowledge, i'm at a loss in my research. Voltage dividers wont work on a varying voltage ? How can I take total output 3.3v and cut it in half?

Comment: Use a voltage divider, resistor values will depend on the characteristics of the ECU input.  A single series resistor may work, again depending on the ECU input cvharacteristics.  However, I'd take the car to a qualified service shop - modifiying car engine controls could be hazardous.

Comment: Voltage dividers work just fine on varying voltages.

Comment: Thank you gentlemen. I used a voltage divider calc and will try some 100 ohm resistors and report back.  Btw I do understand about hacking into a throttle pedal being sketchy but this car is getting fully tuned by me in this project.

Answer (score 0):

Ok gents,  I got the voltage divider done with 200 and 66.7ohms, The output changed the original voltage from
.6v - 3.3v    To  .4v - 1.98. And I wanted to achieve 1.89v MAX voltage so Great!

Although after it was all done, I took the Subaru for a spin and instantly the ECU knew that it was being fooled and left me stuck at the gas pumps for about 5min until i revert back to normal.

On the PLUS side, I used a voltage divider for the 1st time and learned how it works. Thank you much, I will have to bookmark this place and share with friends.